# best way refactoring the ternary operator Java

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-operator

`isCredit` is the common boolean value. Please pay attantion that we put the same values, (but crossing) on debet and credit side depends on boolean

```
 .setDebetSide(new DebetSideDto()
                        .setPayerINN(isCredit ? record.getInnContractor() : record.getClientInn())
                        .setPayerName(isCredit ? record.getNameContractor() : record.getClientName())  
.setCreditSide(new CreditSideDto()
                        .setReceiverINN(isCredit ? record.getClientInn() : record.getInnContractor())
                        .setReceiverName(isCredit ? record.getClientName() : record.getNameContractor())
```

Comment: Please define "best way". What is your goal?

Comment: No need to refactor. The ternary operator is a fully valid operator that makes perfect sense in this situation.

Comment: don't you think guys that it is repetitive code? cuz it only peace of code  @Sam,

Comment: The alternative would be to use `if (isCredit) { ... } else { ... }`. That means you're still repeating stuff, just other stuff - the ``setDebetSide(new DebetSideDto().setPlayerINN(...).setPlaynerName(...))` and the `setCreditSize(...)` parts, with the true or false parts instead of the ternary expressions. Does that make the code more readable? I highly doubt it.

Comment: @AleksandrBerestov Not addressing the repetitiveness, just the irrational fear of the ternary operator (as stated in the title)

Comment: @RobSpoor I do think that using the ternary operator like this is hard to read, and it also requires 4 x branching instead of just one place where branching is required. I've created an answer based on the `if` using the `DebetSideDto` and `CreditSideDto` to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: What if you kept `isCredit` in your `record` and actually kept the logic in `record`. You could even pass the entire `record` to your `Dto` constructors and remove all the faffing about with the setters.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Agreed, but you might have the same issue within the `Dto` constructors, at a somewhat smaller scale perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Try and avoid double calls, so set additional variables in an `if` construct, then call both functions using these variables:

```
var debitSideDto = new DebetSideDto();
var creditSideDto = new CreditSideDto();
if (isCredit) {
    // contractor is payer, client is receiver
    debitSideDto.setPayerINN(record.getInnContractor());
    debitSideDto.setPayerName(record.getNameContractor());
    ...
} else {
    // client is payer, contractor is receiver
    ...
}

.setDebetSide(debitSideDto);
.setCreditSide(creditSideDto);
```

This has the following advantages:

- code branches only once instead of 4 times (lower complexity)
- only two calls per line maximum (a setter with the getter)

As always it sacrifices some conciseness for readability; usually ternary operations are removed to enhance readability.

---

One critique here is that `debitSideDto` was probably designed to contain an invalid state; it is required to call setters to get to a valid state. It's probably better to assign required values upon construction. In that case the constructor needs to be called within the `if` statement. The variable doesn't have to be assigned any value before the `if`; the compiler is fine as long as it **is** assigned a value - it may even be declared `final`:

```
final var debitSideDto;
final var creditSideDto;;
if (isCredit) {
    // contractor is payer, client is receiver
    debitSideDto = new DebetSideDto(
             record.getInnContractor(),
             record.getNameContractor());
    ...
} else {
    // client is payer, contractor is receiver
    ...
}

.setDebetSide(debitSideDto);
.setCreditSide(creditSideDto);
```

---

Alternatively you could create variables for `payerName`, `payerInn`, `receiverName` and `receiverInn` rather than variables for the Dto's of course. That would not remove the invalid states of the Dto's but it would localize that particular issue. On the other hand I'd prefer fewer variables, so I chose to use the Dto's to do the heavy lifting.

I've added some comments though as without these variables the roles are not very clear.

---

This is a localized change of course. In practice I would be wondering why such a reversal of roles is required at this late a stage. I'd be asking questions about the general design (it might be OK, but to me it is a bit of a red flag).

Comment: I've had some issues typing the code with many errors. Please try and provide a more complete example of the code in new questions as it is hard to provide syntax checked code this way.